# Setting --docker-network option on sam build command has no effect

Tags: java, linux, aws-lambda, docker-network, aws-sam-cli

When running

```
sam build --docker-network host
```

and inspecting the initialized Docker container, que can see that default network (bridge) was assigned, that is, the `docker-network` option had no effect.

## Environment details

SAM CLI version: 1.90.0

OS: CentOS 7

AWS region: us-east-1

PackageType: Zip

## Observed result:

`sam build Function --template um-template.yaml --build-dir .aws-sam/build --docker-network host`

`sam local invoke --template um-template.yaml --event "um-event.json" --docker-network host`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS    NAMES
4226540e96f4   public.ecr.aws/...   "/var/rapid/aws-lamb…"   2...     Up...   ...tcp   lambda


CONTAINER ID   STATUS         NAMES      NETWORKS
4226540e96f4   Up 2 minutes   lambda     bridge
```

## Expected result:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS    NAMES
4226540e96f4   public.ecr.aws/...   "/var/rapid/aws-lamb…"   2...     Up...   ...tcp   lambda


CONTAINER ID   STATUS         NAMES      NETWORKS
4226540e96f4   Up 2 minutes   lambda     host
```

Comment: This part of Stack Overflow is "English Only". For Portuguese, please use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/  (Translation by translate.google.com)   /// Esta parte do Stack Overflow é "somente em inglês". Para português, use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (Tradução por translate.google.com)